# a systemd service that starts a dbus service

Tags: systemd, d-bus

I'd like to start a python script that uses `pydbus` to listen for incoming commands via D-Bus on boot, and it needs root permissions. It would be nice if it can be stopped and restarted via `systemctl`, so I don't want to put it into `/etc/rc.local`.

The script is based on [this example](https://github.com/LEW21/pydbus/blob/cc407c8b1d25b7e28a6d661a29f9e661b1c9b964/examples/clientserver/server.py).

I can run the script just fine in a terminal, both in an X11 session and in tty, and send commands to my dbus server. But when starting it via a systemd `.service` file it complains about `gi.repository.GLib.Error: g-io-error-quark: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY (0)`, because I have been using SessionBus. So I went to using SystemBus instead and now get permission errors: `Connection ":1.474" is not allowed to own the service` which is probably associated with the conf in `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/`.

So I looked at some other service to see how they work:

- `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.manjaro.pamac.daemon.service`
- `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.manjaro.pamac.daemon.conf`
- `/usr/lib/systemd/system/pamac-daemon.service`

Is this all the stuff that I need to use? It's just so incredibly troublesome, and everything I try results in new errors.

Are there any good resources on how to do this?

How would one start the linked example above on boot using a systemd `.service` file?

Comment: Can you be more specific on "...it complains about some X11 $DISPLAY stuff." ?

Comment: did. I think I'm getting close, I might just answer my own question at some point today

Comment: I'm still getting a `The name was not provided by any .service files` error

Comment: it was because my pydbus client also needs to use SystemBus to connect. Now it's `GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message`

Comment: It works now, I'm going to make an example setup on github on post it as answer here in the evening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a working example:

https://github.com/sezanzeb/systemd-pydbus-example

I didn't need the `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.manjaro.pamac.daemon.service` file in the end.

Comment: IMO the answer is too short when github code is too complex to me to quickly see how you solved the issues in the question.Could you please add details here?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no short answer to this, the example on github is already as short as it gets. About the specific problems in the question, I don't remember them anymore so I can't give more details about them, sorry